# How to create same bootstrap dropdown menu twice without writing the code twice

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am creating bootstrap dropdown menu in my page ..I need to create same dropdown for different elements...I created one dropdown as follows

```
    <ul>
    <li class="dropdown" id="menu5"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu5"> Settings
    <b class="caret"></b>


</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="" id="kwdList">Content</a></li>
                <li><a>Add
                        User</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="vwUserHier">
                        search</a></li>
                <li><a  href="">Edit</a></li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
```

one menu created correctly but i want to create other menu with the same options how should i do this ...

Is there any way to reuse the contents of dropdown-menu class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried JQuery clone method??
You'll probably have to use it with the 'true' option.